# How to set \n to a str in tcl

Tags: tcl, regsub

Hi I am new to tcl and want to assign "\n" to a variable and use that variable in regsub to replace that string.
It should be like :

```
set a "\n\[\"this is my code\"\]"
puts $a
```

I was expecting this will give
`\n\[\"this is my code\"\]`, then I could use this $a in `regsub {$a} $str "replace" sub_str`.
This regsub could search $a inside $str and replace the matching one with replace and strore it in sub_str.
However, it gave me `[this is my code]`
Is there a way I could get the 1st format as `\n\[\"this is my code\"\]` so I could use that to do the string regsub?

Thanks!

Comment: Backslashing the backslashes is always an option. If you're not doing variable or command substitutions, consider putting things in braces (as _no_ substitutions are done inside there; that's the _real_ meaning of braces in Tcl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use braces instead of quotes to prevent evaluation of the backslash escapes:

```
set a {\n\[\"this is my code\"\]}
puts $a
```

prints

```
\n\[\"this is my code\"\]
```

Comment: Hi Shawn, Thanks for your reply. This works for me. However, if I want do : set $b = "this is my code" and put $b into the set a <...$b...>. what would be the way to also evaluate the content of b as "this is my code"?

Comment: @Shang If I understand you right, something like `set b {"this is my code"}; set a [format {\n\[%s\]} $b]` is probably the cleanest way.

Comment: yes, this is what I mean. Thanks, really appreciate it!